# Se puede usar switch con objetos en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Hola muy días tardes o noches... mi pregunta es la siguiente se pueden usar los switch para comparar objetos?? véanlo de esta forma tengo un una ventana con 3 botones, cada botón cambia el fondo a un color distinto se podría implementar el switch para saber que botón ejecutara el evento?

```
package ClasesInterfaz;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class CreandoMarcoConEventos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MarcoEvento miMarco = new MarcoEvento();
    miMarco.setVisible(true);
    miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}



}

class MarcoEvento extends JFrame{

MarcoEvento(){

    setSize(400,300);
    setLocation(300,200);
    LaminaEvento laminita = new LaminaEvento();
    add(laminita);
}

}

class LaminaEvento extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JButton botonazul = new JButton("Boton azul");
JButton botonRojo = new JButton("Boton Rojo");
JButton botonAmarillo = new JButton("Boton amarillo");

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object objetoEvento = e.getSource();
    if(objetoEvento==botonazul) {
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(objetoEvento==botonRojo) {

        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    else {
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
}

LaminaEvento(){
    add(botonRojo);
    add(botonAmarillo);
    add(botonazul);
    botonazul.addActionListener(this);
    botonAmarillo.addActionListener(this);
    botonRojo.addActionListener(this);
}




}
```

que quiero saber si es posible cambiar los if.. else por switch y si es posible ¿como hacerlo? gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cesar bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor muestra el código donde creas los botones [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/135973/edit). Indica también con claridad cuáles son los criterios que quieres evaluar, pues la pregunta no es del todo clara. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, tan pronto como llegue a casa subiré el código. Muchas gracias por la observación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no puedes usar Switch para comparar objetos por la misma razón que no puedes usar operadores lógicos (== ó !=) para comparar objetos.

Los objetos son instancias, y las variables que los referencian son punteros hacia dichas instancias. Cuando comparas dos objetos, no estás comparando si su "su valor" es idéntico, estás comparando si son la misma instancia, si son el mismo objeto. O dicho de otro modo, Java te responde si ambas variables están apuntando hacia la misma dirección de memoria.

La forma apropiada de comparar si el valor de dos objetos es igual o distinto es utilizando el método heredado ".equals()", y habiéndolo implementado correctamente en su clase, en el caso de que sea un objeto personal que has creado tú mismo.

Hay que tener mucho cuidado cuando comparamos objetos, porque existen casos excepcionales en los que Java aparenta dar resultados coherentes y nos hacen creer que las comparaciones son válidas, como es el caso de la clase String o Integer, pero tienen "truco". En el caso de los String, Java reutiliza instancias cada vez que detecta que existen cadenas repetidas, y en el caso de Integer, existe una cache en un rango específico de números para ahorrar memoria. Pero aunque la comparación parezca dar resultados correctos, NO son fiables.

Answer (score 3):

No, de acuerdo a la [especificación](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=es&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Fspecs%2Fjls%2Fse7%2Fhtml%2Fjls-14.html%23jls-14.11&edit-text=) del lenguaje para la instrucción switch:

> El tipo de Expression debe ser char , byte , short , int , Character ,
>   Byte , Short , Integer , String o un tipo de enumeración ( §8.9 ), o
>   se produce un error en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: Puede que se trate de comparar alguna propiedad obtenida del objeto y en base a dicha comparación decidir que botón mostrar. Eso es lo que he *intuido* al leer la pregunta, en la cual se requiere mayor claridad para entender lo que quiere hacer. En realidad creo que no quiere evaluar un objeto en el `switch` sino determinar que objeto mostrar en base a lo evaluado... Precisamente es esa parte fundamental de la pregunta la que no queda clara: **lo que quiere evaluar en sí**.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible, porque, viendo su documentacion :

[aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) en sus conceptos basicos comenta que * A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types* eso siginfica que un switch solo trabaja con :byte,short,char y enteros, solamente datos primitivos.

y aqui tienes un ejemplo de un switch:

```html
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

**¿Como funciona un Switch?**

Utilización de Switch

Sintaxis del switch.

La Sintaxis empleada por un switch es la siguiente:

```html
switch (variable)  { 
     case <posible valor> : Instrucciones : break;
     case <posible valor> : Instrucciones : break;
     case <posible valor> : Instrucciones : break;
     case <posible valor> : Instrucciones : break;
     case <posible valor> : Instrucciones : break;
     default : Instrucciones ;
```

Dada una variable de entrada esta se define seguido del vocablo switch.

Se abre una llave para iniciar los posibles valores que pueda tomar dicha variable.

Los juegos de valores son iniciados con case seguido del posible valor de la variable, posteriormente es definido un juego de instrucciones que serán ejecutados en caso de corresponder con el valor de la variable y finalmente (opcional) se utiliza vocablo break para salir de ciclo case.

Un valor opcional es la definición de la linea default, cuyas instrucciones serán ejecutadas en caso que la variable del switch no coincida con los valores definidos.

Ejemplo de un switch de los meses :

```html
 
public class Meses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int month = 8;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  System.out.println("Enero"); break;
            case 2:  System.out.println("Febrero"); break;
            case 3:  System.out.println("Marzo"); break;
            case 4:  System.out.println("Abril"); break;
            case 5:  System.out.println("Mayo"); break;
            case 6:  System.out.println("Junio"); break;
            case 7:  System.out.println("Julio"); break;
            case 8:  System.out.println("Agosto"); break;
            case 9:  System.out.println("Septiembre"); break;
            case 10: System.out.println("Octubre"); break;
            case 11: System.out.println("Noviembre"); break;
            case 12: System.out.println("Diciembre"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Meses
Se define un primitivo con valor de 8, el cual es utilizado como variable para un switch.

Dentro del switch son definidos valores del 1 al 12, los cuales tienen como instrucción imprimir a pantalla el valor del mes correspondiente.

Cuando se describió la Sintaxis de un switch se mencionó que el uso de break al final de cada declaración (case) era opcional, esto se debe a la posibilidad que exista más de un valor que deba ejecutar las mismas instrucciones.

fuente de los anterior mencionado:[fuente](https://javabasico.osmosislatina.com/curso/progavanza/switch.htm)